# macro to arrange multiple groups of columns to span full width

Tags: tables, macros

I'm feeding a LaTeX template with content through an external script, and the last formatting step that's resisting me is this one: a macro `\equispace[6]{a,b,c}{d,e,f}{g,h}{i,j,k,l}{m,n,o}{p,q,r,s,t}` that would turn the arguments into an array of this kind,

[image]

where the array extends to the full linewidth, the groups of items are equi-spaced and centred about their own group. I tried something with tabularx and also with minipage, but this is proving trickier than my limited TeX skills allow. Note that I know in advance how many items are in each group, so I could use a hard-coded template if there is a good way to parse the contents.

Comment: always 6 groups or variable what layout is `\equispace[7]...` supposed to do? (and as it is an optional argument what default value?

Comment: And should it always be 3 columns?

Comment: sorry I realise the [6] is pretty meaningless here, in my head it was reminiscent of the \newcommand syntax.

Comment: the number of columns (and items) is fixed indeed

Comment: And I just started to develop something that works for an arbitrary number of items :(

Comment: @Skillmon sorry if it was unclear, however please feel free to add your own strategy, as something more general is always useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the `[6]` argument (see comment under the question) then

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\equispace[6]{%
\begin{center}%
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\zz{#1}\\\zz{#4}\end{tabular}\hfill
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\zz{#2}\\\zz{#5}\end{tabular}\hfill
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\zz{#3}\\\zz{#6}\end{tabular}%
\end{center}%
}

\makeatletter
\def\zz#1{\@for\z:=#1\do{\z\,}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\equispace{a,b,c}{d,e,f}{g,h}{i,j,k,l}{m,n,o}{p,q,r,s,t}

\end{document}
```

Comment: oh actually I permuted the groups from the order that you asked for, but just move `#1` ... `#6` in the definition to change the order.

Comment: If it's a fixed number, why not use one `tabular*` instead?

Comment: very neat, thank you very much! I pictured a strategy along those lines, but the exact syntax would have have eluded me for weeks.

Comment: @Skillmon i was "hedging my bets` if the answer to my question under the original question had been that an argument to support arbitrary number of groups would be needed, then it's easier to extend this than to generate a single table body and fight over `&` appearing in the right places.

Answer (score 1):

If you run an external script, it could output something like the following:

```
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}c@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c@{}}
  a b c &   g h   & m n o\\
  d e f & i j k l & p q r s t
\end{tabular*}
```

Output:
[image]

With lines:

```
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{|@{}c@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c@{}|}
  \hline
  a b c &   g h   & m n o\\
  \hline
  d e f & i j k l & p q r s t\\
  \hline
\end{tabular*}
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

The following should be able to parse an arbitrary number of arguments (and orders it like in your example). The code might not be perfect and could perhaps be enhanced, but it did work on everything I've thrown at it so far.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\makeatletter
\newcount\equi@columns
\newcount\equi@rows
\newcount\equi@args
\newcount\equi@currow
\newcount\equi@curcol
\newcommand\equispace*{}
\def\equispace%
  {%
    \equi@currow=\@ne
    \equi@curcol=\@ne
    \@ifnextchar<
      {\equispace@i}
      {\equispace@i<3>}%
  }
\def\equispace@i<#1>%
  {%
    \equi@columns=#1
    \@ifnextchar[
      {\equispace@ii}
      {\equispace@ii[6]}%
  }
\def\equispace@ii[#1]%
  {%
    \equi@args=#1
    \equi@rows=\numexpr\equi@args/\equi@columns\relax
    \ifnum\numexpr\equi@rows*\equi@columns<\equi@args
      \advance\equi@rows by \@ne
    \fi
    \equi@readarg
  }
\newcommand\equi@readarg[1]
  {%
    \advance\equi@args by \m@ne
    \expandafter\equi@addto@row\expandafter
      {\csname equi@row@\the\equi@currow\endcsname}{\equi@format{#1}}%
    \advance\equi@currow by \@ne
    \ifnum\equi@currow>\equi@rows
      \equi@currow=\@ne
      \advance\equi@curcol by \@ne
    \fi
    \ifnum\equi@args=0
      \expandafter\equi@output
    \else
      \expandafter\equi@readarg
    \fi
  }
\newcommand\equi@addto@row[2]
  {%
    \ifnum\equi@curcol=\@ne
      \def#1{#2}%
    \else
      \edef#1{\unexpanded\expandafter{#1&#2}}%
    \fi
  }
\newcommand\equi@addto@colspec[1]
  {\edef\equi@colspec{\unexpanded\expandafter{\equi@colspec#1}}}
\newcommand*\equi@output
  {%
    \def\equi@colspec{@{}c}%
    \equi@args=\@ne
    \loop\ifnum\equi@args<\equi@columns
      \advance\equi@args by \@ne
      \equi@addto@colspec{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c}%
    \repeat
    \equi@addto@colspec{@{}}%
    \equi@currow=0
    \def\equi@body{}%
    \loop
      \advance\equi@currow by \@ne
      \expandafter\equi@addto@body@expand\expandafter
        {\csname equi@row@\the\equi@currow\endcsname}%
    \ifnum\equi@rows>\equi@currow
      \equi@addto@body{\\}%
    \repeat
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{\equi@colspec}%
      \equi@body
    \end{tabular*}%
  }
\newcommand\equi@addto@body[1]
  {\edef\equi@body{\unexpanded\expandafter{\equi@body#1}}}
\newcommand\equi@addto@body@expand[1]
  {\expandafter\equi@addto@body\expandafter{#1}}
\newcommand\equi@format[1]
  {\@for\equi@tmp:=#1\do{\equi@tmp\,}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\equispace<5>[96]
  {a,b,c}{d,e,f}{g,h}{i,j,k,l}{m,n,o}{p,q,r,s,t}{u,v}{w}{x,y}{z}{1,2}{3,4}
  {a,b,c}{d,e,f}{g,h}{i,j,k,l}{m,n,o}{p,q,r,s,t}{u,v}{w}{x,y}{z}{1,2}{3,4}
  {a,b,c}{d,e,f}{g,h}{i,j,k,l}{m,n,o}{p,q,r,s,t}{u,v}{w}{x,y}{z}{1,2}{3,4}
  {a,b,c}{d,e,f}{g,h}{i,j,k,l}{m,n,o}{p,q,r,s,t}{u,v}{w}{x,y}{z}{1,2}{3,4}
  {a,b,c}{d,e,f}{g,h}{i,j,k,l}{m,n,o}{p,q,r,s,t}{u,v}{w}{x,y}{z}{1,2}{3,4}
  {a,b,c}{d,e,f}{g,h}{i,j,k,l}{m,n,o}{p,q,r,s,t}{u,v}{w}{x,y}{z}{1,2}{3,4}
  {a,b,c}{d,e,f}{g,h}{i,j,k,l}{m,n,o}{p,q,r,s,t}{u,v}{w}{x,y}{z}{1,2}{3,4}
  {a,b,c}{d,e,f}{g,h}{i,j,k,l}{m,n,o}{p,q,r,s,t}{u,v}{w}{x,y}{z}{1,2}{3,4}
\end{document}
```

The command `\equispace` takes two optional arguments, the first enclosed in `<>` is the number of columns and defaults to 3, the second in `[]` is the number of arguments and defaults to 6.

Output for 5 columns and 96 arguments:
[image]

Comment: thanks! The layout is spot on; I'll probably need to ask another question to sort the parsing of values: the content is best provided in the form of one or two lists of characters, say a,b,c,g,h,m,n,o and d,e,f,i,j,k,l,p,q,r,s,t (for the curious, it resides in a YAML metadata file, which is meant to be as readable as possible and void of markup). I know how many items there are, so I'd need some way to parse those strings and fill the tabular template that you proposed.

Comment: @user156626 see my edit for code that parses an arbitrary number of arguments. It always fills one column after the other. There is no check for too many columns, so 4 columns and 6 arguments result in an empty fourth column.

Answer (score 0):

`listofitems` to the rescue!

Uses the syntax: `\equispace{a,b,c/d,e,f/g,h/i,j,k,l/m,n,o/p,q,r,s,t}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems,stackengine,pgffor}
\newcommand\mybox{{\fboxsep=-\fboxrule\fbox{\strut\rule{\linewidth}{0pt}}}}
\newcommand\equispace[1]{%
  \setsepchar[;]{/;,}%
  \readlist*\mylist{#1}%
  \noindent\leavevmode\rlap{\stackunder[-\fboxrule]{\mybox}{\mybox}}%
  ~\foreach\x in{1,3,...,\listlen\mylist[]}{%
    \ifnum\x=1\relax\else\hfill\fi%
    \def\stacktype{L}%
    \stackunder{\foreachitem\y\in\mylist[\x]{\ifnum\ycnt=1\else\ \fi\y}}%
      {\foreachitem\y\in\mylist[\numexpr\x+1]{\ifnum\ycnt=1\else\ \fi\y}}%
  }~%
}
\begin{document}
\equispace{a,b,c/d,e,f/g,h/i,j,k,l/m,n,o/p,q,r,s,t}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like it! Thanks for the original alternative, the syntax is actually more convenient for my use case.

Comment: @user156626 I find a number of cases for which parsing a single long argument is simpler than digesting a large number of separately enumerated arguments.  For such cases, the `listofitems` package is really handy.